# How to get an unsigned long from a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, long-integer

I have an incoming byte array from a piece of test equipment.  The byte array can either be two or four bytes long. I wrote the following code to convert these byte array's into unsigned longs:

```
private ulong GetUlongFrom2Bytes(byte MSB, byte LSB)
{
    return (ulong)((MSB << 8) + (LSB));
}

private ulong GetUlongFrom4Bytes(byte MSB, byte msb, byte lsb, byte LSB)
{
    return (ulong)((MSB << 24) + (msb << 16) + (lsb << 8) + (LSB));
}
```

Conversely, for going the opposite direction, I do the following code:

```
private byte[] Get4Bytes(ulong parm1)
{
    byte[] retVal = new byte[4];

    retVal[0] = (byte)((parm1 >> 24) & 0xFF);
    retVal[1] = (byte)((parm1 >> 16) & 0xFF);
    retVal[2] = (byte)((parm1 >> 8) & 0xFF);
    retVal[3] = (byte)(parm1 & 0xFF);

    return retVal;
}

private byte[] Get8Bytes(ulong parm1, ulong parm2)
{
    byte[] retVal = new byte[8];

    Array.Copy(Get4Bytes(parm1), 0, retVal, 0, 4);
    Array.Copy(Get4Bytes(parm2), 0, retVal, 4, 4);

    return retVal;
}
```

I'm trying to debug my code for controlling this piece of equipment and I'd just like a sanity check from you guys here on SO to confirm that this code is written correctly for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Don't you have unit tests to cover these? That's what will help you ensure they are correct.

Comment: See also `BitConverter` class' static methods

Comment: @I4V you need to be careful with endianness when talking `BitConverter`. My system is little-endian; the OP's code is big-endian; `BitConverter` is system-dependent

Comment: If the data is 2 or 4 bytes, why use `ulong`? `uint` would be plenty sufficient, and it avoids the question of "what to do with the other 4 bytes?"

Comment: Also, IMO the signature of `private ulong GetUlongFrom4Bytes(byte MSB, byte msb, byte lsb, byte LSB)` is very confusing. I would **strongly** advocate a buffer-based API here - like my example below, but `Read32(byte[] buffer, int offset)`

Comment: why are you using `ulong` (a 64 bit int) to represent 32 bit integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want big-endian encoding, then yes: that'll be fine. You *can* also use `BitConverter`, but I think you are right not to - it involves extra array allocations, and forces the system's endianness on you (often little-endian).

Generally, I would recommend such code works with a buffer/offset API, though, for simplicity and efficiency - i.e.

```
private void Write32(ulong value, byte[] buffer, int offset)
{
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)((value >> 24) & 0xFF);
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
    buffer[offset] = (byte)(value & 0xFF);
}
```

Comment: Yes that BitConverter thing has bitten me before. I kindof wish it was a class with a `bool isLittleEndian` constructor parameter.

Comment: @MatthewWatson there's one just like that in MiscUtil, IIRC

Comment: So there is! `MiscUtil.Conversion.EndianBitConverter` Nice, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: The `&0xFF` is superfluous assuming you compile this in unchecked mode. Personally I'd eliminate them and add an `unchecked` block instead. That change would probably speed this code up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
static ulong SliceValue(byte[] bytes, int start, int length)
{
    var bytes = bytes.Skip(start).Take(length);

    ulong acc = 0;
    foreach (var b in bytes) acc = (acc * 0x100) + b;

    return acc;
}
```